# Subsetting a character vector column into multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, text-mining, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have the following tibble:

```
colours = tribble(
  ~all,
  c('blue','green', 'red', 'pink', 'yellow', 'gold', 'orange', 'ivory', 'brown', 'beige'),
  c('green', 'red', 'pink', 'orange', 'ivory', 'beige')
)
```

I would like to split the colours into multiple columns according to their colour family: `Cool`, `Warm`, `Neutral`, with one column for each family.

I can do this using `mutate` with `map` and `str_subset`:

```
colours %>%
  mutate(
    'Cool' = map(all, ~str_subset(., '^(blue|green)$')), 
    'Warm' = map(all, ~str_subset(., '^(red|pink|yellow|gold|orange)$')),
    'Neutral' = map(all, ~str_subset(., '^(ivory|brown|beige)$'))
  )

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  all        Cool      Warm      Neutral  
  <list>     <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 <chr [10]> <chr [2]> <chr [5]> <chr [3]>
2 <chr [6]>  <chr [1]> <chr [3]> <chr [2]>
```

**But I was wondering if there was a more succinct way of achieving the same result?** I've tried `tidyr::extract()` but can't seem to get the regex right:

```
colours %>% 
  mutate(all = map(all, ~paste(., collapse = ' '))) %>% 
  extract(all, into = c('Cool', 'Warm', 'Neutral'), 
          regex = '(blue|green)|(red|pink|yellow|gold|orange)|(ivory|brown|beige)')
```

I'm guessing it's incorrect because the OR statement matches the individual words in each group rather than breaking the string up into three substrings that contain all matched words for each group? [Here is the demo](https://regex101.com/r/0AxrMl/1).

Comment: IMO, data frame columns are not the most appropriate data structure to hold the lists of colors by color family, since there are variable numbers of color in each family. By the 'tidy data' principle you should have one row per color. I would (1) create a CSV lookup table pairing color with family (2) read the table into R (3) left_join the color data with the lookup table.

Comment: Thanks @qdread but I can't tidy it into a long format since the table is intended for presentational/display purposes only in the format described in the post (a column for each colour family). I feel like it could be done with just `extract()` but I'm terrible at regex.

Comment: How is "presentational/display" better served by list columns where you can only see the counts for each vector, but not the colors themselves?

Comment: @gersht because the colours are made visible when the table is rendered using something like `DT::datatable()` - `library(DT); datatable(colours)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was pretty convinced that `extract` wouldn't work, but it does with the right regex. It's really not that much more "succinct" than your first solution, but I think it is probably about as succinct as it can get. (If you want to shorten things think about collapsing your colors into a two element character vector, rather than a dataframe with a list column.)

The issue with your regex pattern is your use of `|`. You want to target collections of words, and not "x OR y OR z", which is what your pattern does, and is why you only get one match per row. To create a collection of possible matches use `[]`. Include `*` for "zero or more" matches. Using your example data above:

```r
library(tidyverse)

colours %>% 
    mutate(all = map(all, str_c, collapse = " ")) %>% 
    extract(all, c("cool", "warm", "neutral"),
            "([blue green]*) ([red pink yellow gold orange]*) ([ivory brown beige]*)",
            remove = F # Include the `all` column.
    )

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  all       cool       warm                        neutral          
  <list>    <chr>      <chr>                       <chr>            
1 <chr [1]> blue green red pink yellow gold orange ivory brown beige
2 <chr [1]> green      red pink orange             ivory beige
```

The main caveat is that the **color categories** need to be in the right order, i.e. the string has to contain groups of color words in the order `cool` → `warm` → `neutral`. If they're random it won't work. In fact, I don't think `extract` would work anymore if the color words were random because there's no way to extract individual words and then concatenate them. You also lose your list columns – if that's important to you.

If the order isn't guaranteed, or if there is a possibility that some category words are missing, then you could do something like the following. Using a random sample of category words (note that I drop the list columns so you can see what's happening):

```r
col_rand <- tribble(
    ~all,
    sample(c('blue','green', 'red', 'pink', 'yellow', 'gold', 'orange', 'ivory', 'brown', 'beige'), 5),
    sample(c('green', 'red', 'pink', 'orange', 'ivory', 'beige'), 4)
) %>% 
    mutate(all = map(all, str_c, collapse = " ") %>% unlist())

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 2 x 1
  all                       
  <chr>                     
1 blue yellow red beige pink
2 ivory pink beige orange
```

And with the following patterns:

```r
patts <- c(cool = "blue|green",
           warm = "red|pink|yellow|gold|orange",
           neutral = "ivory|brown|beige"
           )
```

You could do something like the following, which extracts matches and concatenates them, or returns `NA` if there are no matches:

```r
library(magrittr)

unlist(col_rand$all) %>% 
    map_dfr(function(x) {str_extract_all(x, patts) %>%
            map(function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 0,
                                   NA,
                                   str_c(x, collapse = " ")
                                   )
                ) %>% 
            bind_cols()}) %>% 
    set_colnames(names(patts)) %>% bind_cols(col_rand, .)

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  all                        cool  warm            neutral    
  <chr>                      <chr> <chr>           <chr>      
1 blue yellow red beige pink blue  yellow red pink beige      
2 ivory pink beige orange    NA    pink orange     ivory beige
```

> Note that the `magrittr` library is loaded for the `set_colnames`. If you load `magrittr` after `tidyverse`/`tidyr` you'll need to use `tidyr::extract()` above because both libraries have an `extract` function.

Comment: Thank you for these solutions and for taking the time to explain them so thoroughly @gersht! The order of the words stays the same throughout the actual dataset but I really like the second solution since it's more general. I'm pretty new to `purrr` so your post really helps me out.